# Show multiple categories in query using redux framework variable

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop

Stuck on trying call an option variable using the Redux Framework - that is utilizing multi-category select - inside the query.  Here's what I have as my query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
array( 'category__and' => $my_options['featured_section']  ),
'posts_per_page' => 1 
)); 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
$the_query->the_post();
```

This doesn't work.  The output of `$my_options['featured_section']` is:

```
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 16 )
```

I have two categories selected in the options area, which are ID 20, and ID 16.  Any idea why this won't call the correct categories?

Comment: This doesn't "call the categories" at all. It retrieves posts _if and only if_ the are assigned to both categories. Is that what you want?

Comment: Should I be using:        

    'cat' => $my_options['featured_section']

Yes, I'm looking to retrieve posts that are within the selected categories.

Comment: To retrieve posts in both categories-- not in one or the other or both, but absolutely both-- your code is correct, and using `cat` would be wrong. If that is not the result you see something is interfering, maybe a filter, but I can't guess what.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure, I don't believe there is a filter.  

Here is what I was told by the Redux developer, yet I'm still not grasping it, unfortunately:

"Umm, use the data attribute for the select field and fill args. Like this:

**'data' => 'category',
'args' => array('cat' => $my_options['featured_section'])**

But as you say I should be using 'category__and' as well...

Comment: Their code suggests that `$my_options['featured_section']` is not an array but a comma separated string, which conflicts with what you've said.

Comment: Well, I guess that's what I don't understand, and perhaps why it's not working.  It outputs like this (depending on how many categories are selected):  Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 16 )

Answer (score 1):

I'm Kevin, one of the devs at Redux.  I'd be happy to take a look at your situation more closely if I could get you to hope on over to our github page and submit your issue via our issue tracker https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework.  Please be sure to include the version of Redux you are using (important as we might have a newer version) and a sample of your config, specifically the section you are attempting to use here.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kevin,
Thanks for your post!  I'm working with Redux, migrating from SMOF, and I understand most every use except the multi selection for categories.  I posted at the issue tracker and received a helpful response but am still stuck.  If I don't use the "multi" option (or have it set to false) the query pulls the correct category, but if I have "multi" set to true, the output doesn't work within the query.  Here's the post at the issues tracker that I was offered some help but still failed to grasp :)  https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/issues/909